# SharePoint object model

Tags: 2007, 2010, object-model

I'm looking for articles on custom model mapping for Sharepoint (2007 / 2010). Google's not returning a lot of hits on this, are the any articles out there? Best practices, mapping and such?

I'm looking to build something that can be integrated into both 2007 and 2010, and seeing as SPMetal is only limited to 2010, can't use this on 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the description and implementation of Repository pattern implemented in SharePoint Guidance Library for 2007 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648864.aspx). In 2010 version, they recommend to use repositories with Linq-to-SharePoint, but it works for easy cases and then require a lot of fixes to do simple things. And to support both version (2007 and 2010) it's required to use object model.

Comment: found bart's 2007 version of SPMetal on codeplex. although his initial idea was to use CAML as well, I'm sure it'll guide my in the right way. thanks for the link. interesting read.